# Parts of UI not appearing

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I am attempting to show a small bar underneath my map, however I can not get it to appear on the screen under the map. Where is my mistake? It will show up if my map `height` is set to `"0dp"`, but then the map doesn't appear

Activity XML file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MyActivity">
```

this part shows up fine, don't have any issues

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/EnterLocationLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/enter_location_field"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height"
        android:layout_weight="1.03"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:hint="enter location" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/enter_location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/enter_location_field"
        android:onClick="getAddress"
        android:text="G0!" />

</LinearLayout>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/address_progress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

this fragment shows up but doesn't allow the layout beneath it to be shown

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:id="@+id/map_layout"
        android:layout_below="@id/EnterLocationLayout">
        <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            tools:context=".MyActivity" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

this isn't showing up at all when I run my application unless map height is set to 0dp but map doesn't show

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/destination_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/map_layout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/activity_my_destination"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Destination"
            android:layout_weight="0.82" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/activity_my_destination"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="When I get there I need to..."
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                >
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Remember\nSomething"
                    android:background="#ffffffff" />
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Do\nSomething"
                    android:background="#ffffffff"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Change the height `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` of your `fragment`

Comment: I still have the same problem

Comment: The map fragment probably has no intrinsic height/width which would be why `wrap_content` wouldn't work. You can set the height to some value like 300dp directly, or use layout weight if the parent is a LinearLayout, or use `match_parent` for the map whilst also specifying the `layout_above` attribute (specifying the progress bar)

Answer (score 0):

Your `fragment` has a height of `fill_parent` and it's parent has `wrap_content` so it is taking up the rest of the screen and leaving no room for your bottom layout.

To fix this, change the height of your `fragment` to either `wrap_content` or a fixed height.

You also could fix it by making it's parent `LinearLayout` a fixed `height` but that probably isn't what you want to do.

You also should probably remove the `weight` and `weight_sum` from that layout and probably any that only consist of one layout. There is no need for those and it may be causing an issue.

Comment: I tried all of these suggestions, and nothing worked